# Screen brightness setting maxed but not bright

Tags: laptop, drivers, windows-8.1, display, brightness

Screen brightness setting maxed but not bright.

Hello everyone, this is my first post regarding technical support ever, thanks in advance for any help provided.

I have a Lenovo flex 15 laptop that is running windows 8.1.

As the title stats my screen max brightness had been lowered quite a bit and after messing around with power settings, going to the manufactures website to download another graphics driver, using Google and searching through forums I find myself here wondering what to do next.

My biggest success/temporary fix came from downloading and installing the lenovo recommended driver for windows 8.1(Intel Extreme Graphics Driver) which restored my screen it its full brightness for about 10 minutes before crushing my hoped by reverting back into darkness,  of course I checked the settings again and removed/reinstalled the driver a few times and got similar results each time so I decided to seek out professional assistance if possible.

Comment: Could it be the automatic screen brightness getting in the way? [Disable Auto-Brightness Adjustment in Windows 8.1](http://www.maketecheasier.com/disable-auto-brightness-adjustment-in-windows-8-1/). Or maybe you have inadvertently covered the ambient light sensor.

Answer (score 4):

SOLVED - Go to power options, high performance, change plan settings, advanced, display, change enable adaptive brightness to off

Answer (score 2):

It is most likely caused from low voltage at LCD inverter. This is responsible for producing backlight. You may have to replace the inverter.

Comment: I've had this several times, It has always been a software issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. Triple-check power options, there are presets there of low-power-low brightness that can affect this.
2. Check video drivers to see if you can boost RGB/brigtness from there.
3. Check registry entries and manually impose the high-performance power plan
   To do that, locate and then click the following registry subkey:
   **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\explorer\ControlPanel\NameSpace{025A5937-A6BE-4686-A844-36FE4BEC8B6D}**
   Right-click PreferredPlan, and then click Modify.
   In the Value data box, enter one of the following:
   **8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c** to use the High performance plan.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have checked power options again tried to mess with driver settings and imposed the high-performance power plan, and its still not working.

Comment: Did you notice any difference (even small) when increasing brightness from the display driver ?

Comment: No difference at all so far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

Try rolling back the display driver to the previous version.

Control Panel > Device Manager (opens a window) > Display Adaptors > Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000 (double-click) > Driver (tab) > Roll Back Driver.

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Well some of the laptops have brighness settings in bios setup. For instance dell always have brighness settings under video tab. There you can increase and decrease the brighness. Press F2 go to setup and find video and then ac and dc brighness. Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the answer and found the error because mine was doing the same thing.
Go to Power Options and then "display" and then unclick where it says to adjust the brightness right under the brightness bar.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems with my sis laptop and after all and all going through all the settings even taking it to a technical specialists of which none of them could still find the problem, so there final suggestions was to change the motherboard

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my Samsung laptop.

I tried everything from power settings to changing adaptive brightness.

The only thing that worked was to go to Device Manager > Display adapters > and disabling whatever graphics you are using. That will half solve the problem... because you won't be able to adjust the brightness.

I recommend that you disable it if you want a brighter screen.

Alternatively, what I did was to update my Graphics and that seemed to resolve the issue.

Hope this is helpful to anyone looking at this now :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a **intel** graphics card, you can right click on the main screen, click graphics properties then go to display then color settings and change the brightness there.

(**That does make the colors go weird**)

You can also try to restart your computer

Answer (score 0):

A reboot restored my brightness. Eh, Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I found that Lenovo laptops have a keystroke that instantly zaps your brightness I never remember what is it until I have done it.
I restart laptop, then when the 'Lenovo' logo appears, press the +brightness button.  For me it brings the brightness right back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me on my Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Yoga 3rd Gen with 500 nits Dolby display:

**Click Start > Settings > System > Display**

**Uncheck "Change brightness automatically when lighting changes".**

...This setting doesn't just automatically change what your current brightness is. It limits how bright your display actually is EVEN when you slide the slider all the way up...

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was with the Intel Graphics Power Plan settings, which is located in power options, {POWER PLAN}, change plan settings, change advanced power settings. the problem was my power plan on battery was set to something other than Maximum Performance. I set it to Maximum Performance on both options and all powerplans and now my laptop brightness is fixed to maximum. hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Problem is not in settings for brightness its actualy in driver settings for display , Just click right click and pick graphic setting , then u will find monitor looking icon there and u will see setting for colors , and under colors u should have 3 bars with light , contrast and gama ....those are actualy what makes your screen not so bright ;)

Comment: Read over ["Why do I need 50 reputation to comment"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) to ensure you understand how you can start commenting.

Answer (score -1):

I disabled the integrated graphics chip on my computer which dimmed my brightness significantly. I did this in the first place to fix a game rendering and just turned it back on and my brightness was fixed.

Answer (score -1):

Y'all, my screen brightness setting was not working worth a darn and then i noticed that I could also adjust it by using the keys on the bottom of my monitor. That is what worked for me. I almost ripped my hair out and beat the computer into pieces.