# Laptop screen less bright on Maximum Performance power plan

Tags: windows-10

When I set my power plan to maximum performance, it lowers the brightness of the screen. I do not know why it does this, and this does not happen with power saver or balanced. There is no brightness slider under change plan settings. Does anyone know of a way to fix this? I am on Windows 10.

Comment: is the brightness ok at BIOS screen when your start laptop?

Comment: Here is a similar thread talking about [Screen brightness setting maxed but not bright](https://superuser.com/questions/871462/screen-brightness-setting-maxed-but-not-bright), please check if it was helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

try checking your power&sleep settings, you will see your plans
(power saver/balanced/high performance), you might have to click on the show additional plans toggle.

in your change plan settings you might see a brightness section.

or you could just increase your brightness with your hotkeys on the keyboards (seems the easiest fix)

model number of laptop should help with suggestions if this does not work

Comment: No there is no brightness section in the power plans. And that's the highest it will go. I can't increase it with my keys. I have an ASUSPRO B8430U.